My Visual Studio 2022 compilation insists saying that there is not a file in my solution even though there are no references to that file
Basically I got this problem where I tried to install glad to my project, the thing is that I saw that glew was already there and decided to deinstall glad. But now my Visual Studio keeps asking me for the glad files - here is the error:

Error C1083
Cannot open source file: 'src\vendor\glad\src\glad.c': No such file or directory
OpenGL omg    C:\src\vendor\glad\src\glad.c   1

The thing is that there are no references to that file at all (the following screenshots shows the result of the search in all files).
search result and so on
I also checked in my project properties and the dependencies as well and there is no reference to any file such as glad.c.
I've tried checking my vcxproj.filters file and deleted any kind of reference to that, and also cleaned the solution and recompiled everything. The error is still appears.
Any clue on how to solve this?

just added glad.c (like, a void file for some reason) and then it works. so I have no Idea why this happens
